# Uploading a document to a document set

Tags: 2010

I have a web application that I've added to the _layouts section of a SharePoint application. Originally, I had the page uploading files to a document library. But now, I need to modify the code to upload files to a document set. I am confused on how to do that and the steps to do it. I have the code below which I'm trying to do it, but keep getting errors. First thing I'd like to know, is

1. Can I programmatically upload a document to a document set (like I'm attempting below) or do I need to create something (like a folder maybe) first?
2. Secondly, can some provide or point me to a good code example that I can use?

Below is my code, which I try to reference a document set, which I thought was the way to do it.

```
if (fileUpload.HasFile)
{
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        //SPList list = web.Lists["Awards"];
        SPFolder ds = web.GetFolder(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/Awards/MyDocumentSetName/");

        //Add the initial metadata. We will do an update for all lookup table values, as they need to be done after the record is created.
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add("wfRecipientRank", ddRanks.SelectedValue);
        ht.Add("wfRecipientName", txtRecipientName.Text);
        ht.Add("APFT", rbPassedApft.SelectedValue);
        ht.Add("HeightWeight", rbMeetHtWt.SelectedValue);
        ht.Add("Posthumous", rbPosthumous.SelectedValue);

        //MC 9/25/2012: The commented out line uploads to a document library, whereas the line just below it uploads
        //to a document set.
        //SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUpload.FileName, fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream, ht, false);
        SPFile file = ds.Files.Add(fileUpload.FileName, fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream, ht, false);
        SPListItem item = file.Item;

        //Get the lookup field values
        SPList lookupList = web.Lists["AwardType"];
        int awardTypeId = GetItemId(ddAwardTypes.SelectedValue, lookupList);
        SPFieldLookupValue awardTypeLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();

        if (awardTypeId > 0)
            awardTypeLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(awardTypeId, ddAwardTypes.SelectedValue);

        lookupList = web.Lists["AwardReason"];
        int awardReasonId = GetItemId(ddAwardReasons.SelectedValue, lookupList);
        SPFieldLookupValue awardReasonLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();

        if (awardReasonId > 0)
            awardReasonLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(awardReasonId, ddAwardReasons.SelectedValue);

        lookupList = web.Lists["Priority"];
        int priorityId = GetItemId(ddPriorities.SelectedValue, lookupList);
        SPFieldLookupValue priorityLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();

        if (priorityId > 0)
            priorityLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(priorityId, ddAwardReasons.SelectedValue);

        lookupList = web.Lists["Organization"];

        SPFieldLookupValue organizationLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();
        int organizationId = GetItemId(hiddenOrganizationId.Value, lookupList);

        if (organizationId > 0)
            organizationLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(organizationId, txtOrganization.Value);

        item["Organization"] = organizationLookupValue;
        item["AwardType"] = awardTypeLookupValue;
        item["AwardReason"] = awardReasonLookupValue;
        item["Priority"] = priorityLookupValue;
        item["PresentationDate"] = dpPresentationDate.Value;
        item.Update();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I normally do, but slipped up this time. Appreciate the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/db28b6c7-dd22-424f-bb7d-4480db803e8b

check this Link

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.